# passing values between forms that are placed in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

in index.php there were 2 form .

```
<form method='post' action='res.php' name='form1' id='form1'>
Enter Name<input type='text' name='CardName' >
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
 </form>
```

.
.

```
<form method='post'  action='https://....' name='form2' id='form2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='CardName' id='CardName'  value=''>
 <form>
```

in second form i need to get the value of variable that is submitted  in  the first form.. How to do that? The two forms are in same page,& not allowed to do that using session.Using jquery is preferred . Please help .

Comment: two doubts i have.
1. how you will submit your first form either ajax or http
2. if you will submit your first form than when and how you will come again to second form on same page.
please clear the scenario for this and it will be pleasure to help you

Comment: in res.php i write code for to submitting second form using jquery, and it is working perfectly document.forms["form2"].submit(); .

Comment: 1 doubt.Your problem is when you submit the page (form1 submit) gets reloaded and the value is not available to the next form(form2) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be done in jquery. This may help you..

Add an id to the first form and the field and add an onclick event to the button.

```
<form method='post' action='res.php' name='form1' id="form1" onclick="submitform()">
Enter Name<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
```

and submit the form using jquery like this:

```
function submitform()
{
var name=$('#name').val();
$('#variable').val(name);   // set the value of name field to the hidden field
$('form#form1').submit();   // submit the form
}
```

For second form add `id` to the hidden variable.

```
<form method='post'  action='https://....' name='form2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='variable' id='variable' value=''>
 <form>
```

And you can submit the second form as normal.

In the case, if you are redirecting back to index.php, this method will fail because the hidden field value will get reset once the page is refreshed/reloaded. In that case it is better to pass the value through url like this in res.php file:

```
$val=$_POST['name'];
header('Location: index.php?val='.$val);
```

and in index.php access the value in hidden field like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='variable' id='variable' value='<?php if(isset($_GET['val'])) echo $_GET['val']; ?> '>
```

Comment: is it submitting the form1??

Comment: first form is submitted.

Comment: this is because, you are redirecting back to index.php from res.php.

Comment: yes..But how can i solve that?.Please help if you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the value attribute of your hidden input:

```
<?=$_POST["name"];?>
```

You likely want to only echo the value if `isset` returns true.

Comment: never ever use shorthand code in php.
use <?php echo $_POST['name'];?>

Comment: Sure, I'm on mobile right now however. What's the actual reason behind not using short open tags?

Comment: Thanks Neel but these shorthand operators are deprecated in php so it will become an warning. we call this style Servlet style

Answer (score 0):

try this 
first place an id for form,then try below code

```
$( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var valForm1 = $(this).find('input').val();
  $( "#form2").find('input').val(valForm1 );
});
```

may be the get and set value is not right but i think the idea can work